# Adding Colorbar legend to Basemap plot containing multiple shapefiles

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using Basemap to draw several shapefiles to one canvas, coloring with an index I calculated before. Now I'm trying to add a legend (colorbar) next to my image, but I can't get it to work. This is my code so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Floats between 0 and 20
indexList = [*Previously calculated indices*]
minIndex = min(indexList)
maxIndex = max(indexList)

# Figure out colors for each index
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=minIndex, vmax=maxIndex, clip=True)
mapper=cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='RdYlBu')

for key in indexList
    gridIndexDict[key] = mapper.to_rgba(indexList[key]) #

# Map to draw on, minX etc. won't interest here
m = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0=(minX+maxX)/2, lon_0 = (minY+maxY)/2,
    resolution='h', area_thresh=0.1,llcrnrlon=minX, llcrnrlat=minY, 
    urcrnrlon=maxX, urcrnrlat=maxY)

# Yes, that's 1000 shapefiles
for i in range(0, 40):
    for j in range(0, 25):
        path = "Some path using i and j"
        m.readshapefile(path, "Title", color=gridIndexDict["Key using i and j"])

###
# I think this is the place to add a colorbar legend?
###
plt.show()
```

Basically I'm using the two loops to read and paint shapefiles with a previously determined color. The individual shapefiles are painted in the correct color, but I can't get the colorbar to even show up.

I've spent hours trying to dig through documentations and examples, but couldn't get anything to work.
Maybe some of you can help me with this? Please let me know if I need to provide more information for you.

Comment: `fig.colorbar(mapper)`?

Comment: Gives me the error: The name `fig` is not defined.

Comment: You will need to get a reference to your the figure you are working with, ex `fig = plt.gcf()`

Comment: I just worked at my code a bit more, and it works... Thank you so much!

Comment: What you're writing is working as well. Please post that as an answer, so I can give credit where credit is due!

Comment: You should answer your own question, I do not have the bandwith to write a proper answer right now and do not really care about the rep ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On behalf of @tcaswell, I write this answer in his stead:

```
mapper.set_array(indexList)
plt.colorbar(mapper)
```

works as well as

```
fig = plt.gcf()
mapper.set_array(indexList)
fig.colorbar(mapper)
```